# Setting start date parameter on private blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, genesis

I have a private blockchian and I am using Parity's chain spec to create it.  The first block always gets labeled as 01/01/70 and I wonder what I must change in order to set it to today's date?

Comment: In the genesis section there's an optional field named timestamp, it is the genesis block timestamp in unix time format (https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Chain-specification).

Comment: @Ismael Thank you!  I've looked at that page so many times, but didn't see it.  And I was searching for "date" and "start" but not "time" for some reason.  Thank you.  If you want to make this an actual answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: I do not have parity client to test with, if you have a specs sample that works it will be good f you answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ismael says, "In the genesis section there's an optional field named timestamp, it is the genesis block timestamp in unix time format" so that means using a converter like this and entering that value as your timestamp value:
https://www.epochconverter.com/